# Rate Limiting does not work in dingo laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, dingo-api

According to [this guidance](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Rate-Limiting) ,I added a throttle functionality to a specific route in my laravel project like this :

```
$api->group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function ($api) {
    $api->post('checkUser', ['middleware' => 'api.throttle', 'limit' => 3, 'expires' => 20, 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@checkUser']);
});
```

As you can see I added a throttle , limit of **3** with an expiration time of **20** minutes for this specific route.

But even I request that rout more than **3** times, no things occurred.

I do not know what is problem or is need any more step or not?

**Update:**

After check `php artisan api:route` I found that no middleware assigned to that specific route. I do not know why?

Comment: I've never seen the middleware being defined in that way before. Is it documented?

Comment: @apokryfos,https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Rate-Limiting#require-rate-limiting-on-specific-routes